# Understanding the <$> operator

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have the following type:

```
newtype Rep f a = Rep { runRep :: String -> f (String, a) }
```

The type Rep f a is a stateful computation that takes a String as the initial state and produces a (String, a) as the result of the computation. The result of the computation is wrapped in the functor  f.

The applicative instance for Rep is the following:

```
instance Monad f => Applicative (Rep f) where 
    pure x = Rep $ \s -> pure (s, x)
    Rep f <*> Rep x = Rep $ \s -> do 
        (s',rf)  <- f s 
        (s'',rx) <- x s'
        return (s'', rf rx)
```

And the monad instance for Rep is the following:

```
instance Monad f => Monad (Rep f) where 
   return x = pure x 
   Rep a >>= f = Rep $ \s -> do
    (s', ya) <- a s
    let (Rep f') = f ya
    (s'', yf) <- f' s'
    pure (s'', yf)
```

I have the following data types and function:

```
data TD = Empty | Fol TD TD | Letters [Char]

data Res = Nil | Character Char | Cop Res Res | Special [Res]

findmatch (Fol a b) = do
   ra <- findmatch a
   rb <- findmatch b
   pure (Cop ra rb)

findmatch (Fol a b) = Cop <$> findmatch a <*> findmatch b
```

I am having trouble understanding how the second definition of `findmatch` involving the `<$>` works. I know that `<$>` has the following type declaration:

```
(<$>) :: (Functor f) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
f <$> x = fmap f x
```

The first argument to `<$>` should be a function, whilst the second should be a value wrapped in a functor. The result of `findmatch` is a value wrapped in a functor, however is `Cop` a function in this case? I know that `Cop` is a value constructor that takes two arguments of type Res. If one argument of type Res is passed to Cop, which is what I think occurs in `Cop <$> findmatch a`, this would return another function which takes a value of type Res. However, I am not sure what would be the type of the result that is returned by this second function that resulted from the partial application.

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: You need to look at the `Applicative` instance for `Rep` to understand why the two are equivalent. The shorter answer is that there is no data dependency between the two recursive calls to `findmatch`, so the `Monad` instance unnecessarily forces one to run before the other. The `Applicative` instance does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However is `Cop` a function in this case? I know that `Cop` is a value constructor that takes two arguments of type `Res`.

Yes, `Cop` is a function with two parameters. It has the type `Cop :: Res -> Res -> Res`.

> If one argument of type `Res` is passed to Cop, this would return another function which takes a value of type `Res`.

Yes. `Cop <$> findmatch a :: Functor f => f (Res -> Res)`

> What would the type of the result that is returned by this second function that resulted from the partial application.

It's the type of the value that is constructed by the `Cop` constructor: it's constructing `Res` values.

Comment: Since Cop is a value constructor, am I correct in saying that it takes values of type Res and constructs a value that is of type Res?

Comment: @ceno980 Yes, exactly that. In comparison, `Letters` takes a `[Char]` and constructs a `TD`, and `Character` takes a `Char` and constructs a `Res`.